# How to login and do POST request with Login Cookie

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to create a bot which will login to the website and after logging in it is going to do a POST request in that website.

I want to use WebClient or anything like this. 
The site I want to login and do a POST request is "https://login.sabanciuniv.edu/cas/login"

Also it would be cool if I can check if login process is succeeded.

(If any grammar or language specific mistake, please forgive me I'm not native :) )

Oğuzhan(Oguzhan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a cookieawarewebclient by extending the webclient:

```
private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient()
        : this(new CookieContainer())
    { }
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

        var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
        if (castRequest != null)
        {
            castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }

        return request;
    }
}
```

and create a post request that simulates the login. For that you can use Fiddler where you can see the exact thing that is going on when you click on submit button and you simply do the same in the code.

Comment: Okey, now I'm trying to use this CookieAwareWebClient but I couldnt make it work. http://www.pastebin.ca/2458890 
Error is in HtmlResult